# How to get MJPG frames in HTML5 using VLC streaming server?

Tags: javascript, html, vlc, mjpeg

I have VLC streming server, on which I started two streams:

```
vlc -vvv -d http://*camera_adress* --sout '#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=vorb,ab=128}:standard{access=http,mux=ogg,dst=*server_name*:20000}'
vlc -vvv -d http://*camera_adress* --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=mpjpeg,dst=*server_name*:21000}'
```

1) Ogg with HTML5 works fine, I am receiving stream from video tag.

2) Mjpg on mobile it works fine, but I don't know how to get MJPG frames in html5. I tried to use JavaScript from http://wiki.ros.org/mjpegcanvasjs/Tutorials/CreatingASingleStreamCanvas but it doesn't work. VLC Media Player receives stream, so this is not the server or stream problem.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I get it. It's better to start stream like this:

```
vlc -d -vvv http://camera_ip/mjpg/video.mjpg --no-audio --sout '#transcode{vcodec=MJPG,venc=ffmpeg{strict=1}}:standard{access=http{mime=multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=--7b3cc56e5f51db803f790dad720ed50a},mux=mpjpeg,dst=server_name:port}' &
```

Then U can get this stream as a normal jpg in HTML5, using simple tag:

```
<img src>
```

Comment: I am new to this. To check if I streamed it correctly, do I click on Media >> Open Network Stream >> (under URL) http://server_name:port

Comment: @maryhadalittlelamb it's not showing anything after pressing play button on VLC, how did you visualize the output? I am trying to use Droidcam

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer should still be fine but today, manual MIME type specification is no longer necessary if the output file name is given with a `mpjpeg` extension:

```
vlc -I dummy "file.mp4" --no-audio --sout=#transcode{vcodec=MJPG,height=720,fps=4,vb=800}:http{mux=mpjpeg,dst=:8080/video.mpjpeg}
```

Comment: On Windows (using PowerShell), the value of the `--sout` option needs to be enclosed in quotes.